# Can I return different values ​with for in foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach, laravel-blade

Every time the foreach returns, it writes the element with values[0] because $i=0. I want foreach to print values[0] when it returns first and values[1] when it returns second. Where exactly should I do the for loop?

```
@foreach ($videohistories as $videohistory)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $videohistory->create_time) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $videohistory->end_time) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ diff_date_format($videohistory->begin_time, $videohistory->end_time, "%H sa %i dk. %s sn") }}</td>
                    <td>
                        @for($i = 0; $i < $values; $i++) {{$values[$i]}} @break @endfor </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: If you want it to output _one_ value in each iteration of the `foreach`, then why would you use a `for` loop in that place to begin with? You probably rather need a simple loop counter, and use that. (Assuming you have as many entries in $values, as you have in $videohistories - but your question is lacking any actual details about what data you are dealing with here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a for loop in each iteration and then breaking out at the first iteration of that loop. If you want to print the i-th element based on the `foreach` iteration you need to use the [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable

```
@foreach ($videohistories as $videohistory)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $videohistory->create_time) }}</td>
         <td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $videohistory->end_time) }}</td>
         <td>{{ diff_date_format($videohistory->begin_time, $videohistory->end_time, "%H sa %i dk. %s sn") }}</td>
         <td>
             @if (isset($values[$loop->index])) 
                 {{$values[$loop->index]}}
             @endif
         </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That was the logical thing, I didn't write it thinking it wouldn't happen even though I thought so, thanks @apokryfos